# Pandas delete row if matches string (case-insensitive)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete rows in my dataframe if it contains something from my list.

DF

```
Search_List = ['drunk', 'owner']
df = df[~df['Searches'].str.contains('|'.join(Search_List))]

Searches
the person was Drunk
the owner was not available
This is a test
The Owner was not in
```

Current Result:

```
Searches
the person was Drunk
This is a test
The Owner was not in
```

Expected Result:

```
Searches
This is a test
```

is there a way to conduct the search but allow it to match even if it is upper cases etc? I am unable to convert it to lower and then do the search as it breaks the other functions i have in the script. Is there an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `case=False` parameter to [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
Search_List = ['drunk', 'owner']
df = df[~df['Searches'].str.contains('|'.join(Search_List), case=False)]
print (df)
         Searches
2  This is a test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the strings to `lowercase` before checking.

```
df = df[~df['Searches'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(Search_List))]
```